# Prove sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n = (1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4}) ... (1+\frac{1}{2^n})$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges.

I know we have to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded above. I was able to show that the sequence is increasing but I don't know how to show that it is bounded above. Maybe we can use the sequence for $e$?

Comment: We don't need to show the limit, just that it converges.

Comment: See here: [Convergence infinite product.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964181

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take the logarithm of our product, and use the fact that for positive $x$ we have $0\lt \ln(1+x)\lt x$. That gives $e^1$ as an upper bound.